# How to address numpy warning message about array stacking?

Tags: python, numpy

I've seen the numpy deprecation message,  "FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple" appear in various threads but don't see the most pythonic way to address it for my simple situation of a three-dimensional array:

```
import numpy as np
X=np.random.rand(3,4,5)
Y= np.vstack(X[:, :, x].T for x in range(1,3)) # vertically stack X[:,:,0], X[:,:,1], etc.
```

The resulting error message is

> Warning (from warnings module):   File "<pyshell#2>", line 1
> FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type
> such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as
> generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in
> the future.

Comment: `Y= np.vstack([X[:, :, x].T for x in range(1,3)])` Just as the waring says `arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple` So pass them as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment.

If I define a simple function:

```
def foo(x):
    return x
```

and call it as you did `vstack`:

```
In [53]: foo(x[:,0] for x in np.ones((2,3,3)))
Out[53]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc5d961bc10>
```

The `for` expression created a generator.  We have to wrap it in `list` to get an actual list:

```
In [54]: list(_)
Out[54]: [array([1., 1., 1.]), array([1., 1., 1.])]
```

Adding [] to your expression creates the list:

```
In [55]: foo([x[:,0] for x in np.ones((2,3,3))])
Out[55]: [array([1., 1., 1.]), array([1., 1., 1.])]
```

Other syntax for making a generator versus a list:

```
In [56]: (x[:,0] for x in np.ones((2,3,3)))
Out[56]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc5d02a1190>
In [57]: [x[:,0] for x in np.ones((2,3,3))]
Out[57]: [array([1., 1., 1.]), array([1., 1., 1.])]
```

Code for functions like `vstack` was written in way that works with generators, but developers are working to clean up details like this, making things more consistent.